# How we can add popup for context menus

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have created a chrome extension. I have used **Selection and all** context menus. I want to know how we can add popup error if any text is not selected from the page.

If any text selected then it should not show any error message.

Comment: You can use the standard `alert()` or run a content script in the active page to add a beautifully styled DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below code to display pop up:

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
id: "context1",
title: "selected",
contexts: ["all"]
});

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab) {
  if (tab) {
    if (info.menuItemId === "context1"){
        var code = 'alert("text selected");';
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { code: code });
    }
}
});
```